# Having actions/pages without requiring a login

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am building an application using cakePHP. Do we have a method where we can allow public users access to certain pages without logging in. There would be a few pages such as about us regarding the whole organisation or a contact us page. Is there a method to avoid login access, something similar to how we have ways to add components or set layouts.

Comment: you can make use of ACT + AUth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Bean says, you can use ACL. For a sophisticated site, that would be my choice. You do not have to be logged in to access the public pages. http://multiheadweighers.co.uk is an example of a site that uses ACL. There is a fully featured CMS behind the public pages.

For a simple site I would allow access to, for instance, the view action using

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter;
    $this->Auth->allow('view');
}
```

see: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1257/allow

It really isn't a big deal - try it and you'll see how easy it is.

EDIT:

From the book @ http://book.cakephp.org/view/1550/Setting-up-permissions

> Now we want to take out the references
>   to Auth->allowedActions in your users
>   and groups controllers. Then add the
>   following to your posts and widgets
>   controllers:

```
function beforeFilter() 
{    
    parent::beforeFilter();     
    $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('index', 'view');
}
```

This removes the 'off switches' we put in earlier on the users and groups controllers, and gives public access on the index and view actions in posts and widgets controllers. In AppController::beforeFilter() add the following:

```
 $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display');
```

This makes the 'display' action public. This will keep our PagesController::display() public. This is important as often the default routing has this action as the home page for you application.

EDIT 2:

```
    $user = ($this->Auth->user())?$this->Auth->user():'Anonymous';
    if(!$this->Acl->check($user,"{$url}"))
        $this->redirect($this->referer()); // or whatever action you want to take.
```

Comment: isn't ACL used for controlling the access rights for registered users?? How would ACL be a part in letting unregistered users to access to public pages?? It should be done by the Auth component isn't it? Could you please explain how ACL can be used for this?

Comment: Yes it is, but that doesn't mean EVERYTHING has to be controlled by ACL - there can be exclusions. See my edit above. I have encountered some sticky situations where I've had to do something like my second edit.

Comment: You don't need to use ACL - just `$this->Auth->allow(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to use the allow method in the Auth component to let the user visit those pages.

Thank you!